# Only display table in the_content() in canonical page

Tags: functions

please help me to display only tables on a canonical page

main page
https://www.printerdriverforwindows.com/hp-deskjet-ink-advantage-3700-driver

```
    <table style="height: 198px; width: autopx;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 20.8px;">
<td style="width: 333.283px; height: 20.8px; text-align: center;"><strong>Filename</strong></td>
<td style="width: 56.7167px; height: 20.8px; text-align: center;"><strong>Size</strong></td>
<td style="width: 195px; height: 20.8px; text-align: center;"><strong>Download</strong></td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

want to display table content only on the download page

now using `<?php the_content(); ?>`

which shows full content

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Let put the following code at the end of file `functions.php` on the theme or child theme.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_show_table_on_download_page', 20);
function custom_show_table_on_download_page() { 
    if(is_single()){
        echo '<style type="text/css">.dpage {display: none !important;}</style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code not working site down when the above code added

Comment: @AshijaPramod Please send me a screenshot :D

Comment: which one function.php

Comment: add_action('wp_head', 'custom_show_table_on_download_page', 20);
function custom_show_table_on_download_page() { 
    if(is_single()){
        echo '<style type="text/css">.dpage {display: none !important;}</style>';
    }
});

Comment: added below function.php

Comment: It is functions.php, not function.php :D

Comment: genesis/functions.php

Comment: genesis/functions.php the code added below check the file https://www.mediafire.com/file/uph5mc91cuppam5/functions.php/file

Comment: I have updated the code. Please try that again!

Comment: i have updated the code this time website working but shows entire post on download page no changes

Comment: .dpage{
    display:none !important;
}      added on download page and used <div class="dpage">  </div> to hide the other contents that works if i can use same method for showing content then i can fix my problem

Comment: only show the content within that code